# Using Regex in Notepad++ to Replace a Character

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a large notepad++ file and have an instance where a field has 16 length that can contain numbers and letters followed by a comma and then another field that starts with letters. I am trying to make sure the next field after the comma starts with a ".

So far I have this regex. I checked it with ruby expressions and it appears right. I just don't know how to insert a " after the comma to begin the next field. This is probably really easy I am just missing something here. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{16}\,[a-zA-Z]+)
```

So I want to add a " after the escaped comma above.

Comment: What's wrong with just adding `\"` after the `\,` for the comma?

Comment: @KenWhite the OP is trying to do a search and replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options.

You could use [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and write back what you matched (in addition to the quotes):

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{16},)([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Each set of parentheses generates a captured group. You can reference what they matched with `$n` in the replacement string: `$1"$2`.

Note that there is no need to escape the comma.

The alternative is [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). What you match inside a lookaround is not part of the match, so it doesn't get removed. If you put everything around the desired position in lookarounds, you'll match a position instead of a string, and the replacement string will simply be inserted in that position:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9]{16},)(?=[a-zA-Z]+)
```

And replace that with `"`.

In any case, make sure to upgrade to Notepad++ 6.

Finally note that in both cases the `+` at the end is irrelevant - if there's one letter, there is also "one or more letters". (There is a very unlikely edge-case where it would make a difference, but that is probably beyond the scope of this question.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the first answer and it worked. I had never used replace when using regex in notepad++ just find. From now on I will now how to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]{16}\,\"[a-zA-Z]+)
```